# n planes intersection

Tags: math, 3d

I have n 3D planes each with distance 1.0 from the origin. I know they all intersect at a point in space. I know each planes normal (and a point on each plane, since they all distance 1.0 from the origin, along the normal).

Is there a way to calculate this intersection? I know how to calculate an intersection of 2 or 3 planes, but I dont know how to proceed with a variable number of planes

Thank you

Comment: quick internet search should answer this....

Comment: not really, its 3 days im googling but everything is about 2 or 3 planes only

Comment: why not just pick 3 planes and find their intersection point? If there are more planes that happen to pass through that point it makes no difference in the calculation.

Comment: yes im doing just that.. but i get different results I was wondering maybe its not the right approach (for some reason).. but i'll review my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The intersection of 2 planes is a line. The intersection of 3 planes is a point in the 3D space.
So, of all the planes, select any 3 planes and find their point of intersection. All other planes (if they are indeed intersecting at the same point) will also intersect at this point. That is the point you're looking for!

Comment: uh.. this is what im actually doing.. but i keep getting a different vector every time I pick 3 different planes.. maybe its my code?

Comment: Well, logically what you're doing is correct. Probably its your code. This might help: http://softsurfer.com/Archive/algorithm_0104/algorithm_0104B.htm#Intersection%20of%203%20Planes

Comment: Make sure that the 3 planes that you choose to compute the point of intersection are not collinear. Otherwise you may not get the correct intersection point.

Comment: Oh yes, that's important! Missed out on that.

Comment: definitely my code.. sorry.. im glad what im doing is correct btw

Answer (score 0):

Typically, one defines a plane by the a point (P) on the plane, and the normal vector (N) to the plane. This definition works in any number of dimensions of course, since P and N are general vectors. Thus, a point X is in the plane if

```
dot(X - P,N) == 0
```

We can rewrite that dot product in the form

```
dot(X,N) == dot(P,N)
```

Of course, these dot products can be expanded into a simple linear equation in the variables of X.

How does all of this translate into equations we can use and write down? In 3-d, for example one might consider the plane that passes through the point [1 2 3], with the normal vector [1 0 2].

Thus a point [x,y,z] is in that plane if the following equation holds true:

```
dot([x,y,z],[1,0,2]) == dot([1 2 3],[1 0 2])
```

or,

```
x + 0*y + 2*z = 7
```

My point is, if you have a single plane in 3-d, it corresponds to a single equation in the unknowns [x,y,z]. If you have multiple equations (multiple planes) in those three unknowns, then you have a linear system of equations.

You should use linear algebra to solve that system of equations. When there are more than 3 equations, the system (assuming the various planes do not form a singular system) will generally have no exact solution that satisfies all of the equations. This is called an overdetermined system, and a linear least squares solution is used to solve for the set of parameters [x,y,z] that minimizes the sum of squares of the residuals.